# Youtube API Direct Upload and Return URL, Possibly in Ajax?

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

Alright, here's the situation.

I've got the Youtube API working to upload a video. Once it is uploaded, it returns http://example.com/?status=200&id=3-1234xyz.

Ideally, I'd like to have this submitted and uploaded via Ajax and then have the ID returned to immediately display on the page (that will eventually show the URL or embed code for the video). I'm using jquery, but I'm at my whits end with all of this. Any and all help, links, etc are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an iframe. You simply post the file upload form into the iframe, when it's then finished loading (you can capture this event with $('#iframe').ready( ... )) you can then capture the video id (cos it's on the same domain).

So your upload form will be along the following lines:

```
<form action="...?nexturl=IFRAME_URL" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploader">
<p>Please select the video you wish to upload to YouTube:</p>
<input type="file" name="file" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="" />
<button>Upload</button>
</form>
<iframe id="uploader" name="uploader" style="display: none; width: 1px; height: 1px; border: none;"></iframe>
```

And then all your iframe needs to do is just pass the video id up to the parent (or you can read it from the parent, but I prefer the former):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        var vars    = getVars();

        $( document ).ready( function()
        {
            parent.selectVideo( vars[ 'id' ] );
        });

        function getVars()
        {
            var vars = [];
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            var hash;

            for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
            {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');

                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }

            return vars;
        }
    -->
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

And job done :D

Comment: So I put this together and it worked perfectly, except for giving me the video ID back to then embed. I'm seeing the parent.selectVideo() but I'm not sure exactly how I'm supposed to use this. Thank you so much for your answer btw, I'm almost 100% complete!

Comment: Update: Using Firebug's console, I got this error: parent.selectVideo is not a function
[Break On This Error] parent.selectVideo( vars[ 'id' ] );

Comment: Figured it out: parent.$("p.youtubeid").append(document.createTextNode( vars['id'] ));

Comment: Cool, sorry I didn't get your comments.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use this, but target="uploader" opens new window...can you, please, tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Found solution - needs ID and NAME :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083325/firefox-form-targetting-an-iframe-is-opening-new-tab

Comment: Thanks a lot man! But you should be a little more clear about the target="idOfMyIframe" and IFRAME_URL thing. Basically IFRAME_URL is any php or server file that reads the ID parameter, and prints it, so we can be able to read it after, from the iframe content, when iframe is ready. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Im using this, and it's working nice, issue is, I can't interrupt or do something before form is submitted, nor in onclick parameter for input submit, or in onsubmit in the form, everytime I try to interrupt the form to disable the form and show it just started loading, I get an error code sending the form. Any Ideas?