# Youtube API - uploading videos via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using standard Zend Youtube library to upload videos to Youtube. It's working well, but I need the uploader to work without refresh.

I tried to achieve it but I always got:
**302 Found** response from youtube upload url,
**400 Missing token** was sent to my script

Method that creates uploader

```
public static function showUploadForm($presenter, $id, $name, $comment) {

    $yt = self::getYt(); // these are the account settings

    // create a new VideoEntry object
    $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

    $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle($name);
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription($comment);
    // The category must be a valid YouTube category!
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('People');

    // Set keywords. Please note that this must be a comma-separated string
    // and that individual keywords cannot contain whitespace
    $myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('hockey');

    $tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
    $tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($myVideoEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);
    $tokenValue = $tokenArray['token'];
    $postUrl = $tokenArray['url'];

    // place to redirect user after upload
    $nextUrl = $presenter->link('//User:videoUploaded', array('id' => $id)); //framework action


    // build the form
    $form = '<form id="youtubeUploader" class="ajaxSetVideoData" action="' . $postUrl . '?nexturl=' . $nextUrl .
            '" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">' .
            '<input id="file" name="file" type="file" />' .
            '<input name="submit" type="submit" value="send" />' .
            '<input name="token" type="hidden" value="' . $tokenValue . '"/>'.
            '</form>' .
            '<br />';
    return $form;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**: I've found out that only input "token" is send as parameter to the youtube URL.

**EDIT2**: There was a problem with AJAX and file upload. With this plugins it's working:
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples

But now still get 302 Found in both scripts, but "status" in the URL is 200 (second line), which is OK - video is also uploaded.
[image]

Comment: Well, here is one...its just zend youtube uploader

Comment: http 302, is a redirect. Guess this has to do with the fact that you POST data to another domain and that's why it's "red" to warn about XSS maybe? sorry for my late answer :)

Comment: No problem :) I have browsed the Web and found out that the best thing is to use IFRAME instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with AJAX and file upload. With this plugins it's working:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples

**SOLVED**: Solution is that you should use IFRAME as asynchronous upload. Look here:

[Youtube IFRAME uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752366/youtube-api-direct-upload-and-return-url-possibly-in-ajax)